# I'm unable to install Firefox in WSL

Tags: shell, terminal, firefox, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
$ sudo apt install firefox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package firefox
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more details, starting with what operating system you are using. Why is putty relevant? The error is quite clear: there is no package named `firefox` available, but we can't help more unless you tell us what system you are using. If, as seems to be the case, this is some sort of Debian derivative, please also show us the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: I'm using the windows machine

Comment: cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

Comment: Please ***[EDIT]*** your question to add the information. You can use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Make sure to explain exactly what you are doing. I think you mean you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux but, if so, why is `putty` relevant?

Comment: We're making some assumptions here based on your lack of detail.  @terdon has tagged this as [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux] based on the output you provided, and I agree that's likely the case even though you don't mention WSL in the question.  Based on that, I've also edited the title and provided the most likely answer for your problem.  But please do read our [How do I ask a good question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page.  Hopefully I've answered your question, but you'll have much better chances of getting an answer if you provide more info.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely, if you just installed WSL and (assuming, but you don't mention the exact distribution) Ubuntu (but could be any Debian-based distribution) that you haven't performed a critical first-step:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

It's really the first step in using any Debian-based distribution from the command-line, even when not using WSL.

Really only the first `update` part is *required* to install Firefox, but the second `upgrade` is highly recommended to bring your system up-to-date.

For the first part, most WSL distributions don't ship with the package cache populated, to save on download bandwidth.  So you need to do this *regardless* on WSL.

The second part, upgrading, is recommended for the same reason you do a Windows Update after first installing -- The *installed* packages are almost always somewhat out-of-date, and updated packages have been released since the time the distribution was distributed.

That said, note that you will need to be running Windows 11 in order to *use* the Linux version of Firefox in WSL, at least without additional configuration.  See [my Super User answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1669770/1210833) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled the security repository:

Fix:

```
sudo sed -i '/security/s/^# //' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Update the repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then you should be able to install firefox:

```
sudo apt install firefox
```